# Loadtests with Hazelcast: Increase maximum number of parallel connections

Tags: java, load-testing, hazelcast

We are currently performing some load tests with Hazelcast (v3.3.2). Once the number of parallel connections gets larger than 500, exceptions are thrown and the master node of the cluster shuts down automatically. I couldn't find much info on the exception, so I was wondering if there is somehow a maximum number of parallel connections that I have to increase in the config file.

Here is the exception:

```
com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is not ready yet!
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.ClientEngineImpl$ClientPacketProcessor.processRequest(ClientEngineImpl.java:428)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.ClientEngineImpl$ClientPacketProcessor.run(ClientEngineImpl.java:358)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$BasicDispatcherImpl.dispatch(BasicOperationService.java:546)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationScheduler$OperationThread.process(BasicOperationScheduler.java:439)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationScheduler$OperationThread.doRun(BasicOperationScheduler.java:433)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationScheduler$OperationThread.run(BasicOperationScheduler.java:408)
    at ------ End remote and begin local stack-trace ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientCallFuture.resolveResponse(ClientCallFuture.java:194)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientCallFuture.get(ClientCallFuture.java:136)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientCallFuture.get(ClientCallFuture.java:113)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:110)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.put(ClientMapProxy.java:323)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.put(ClientMapProxy.java:189)
    at com.hp.cms.rtc.benchmarksuite.dbconnectors.HazelcastConnectorImpl.saveDevice(HazelcastConnectorImpl.java:154)
    at com.hp.cms.rtc.benchmarksuite.dbconnectors.HazelcastConnectorImpl.insertNewCustomer(HazelcastConnectorImpl.java:317)
    at com.hp.cms.rtc.benchmarksuite.usecases.InsertNewCustomerUseCaseImpl.execute(InsertNewCustomerUseCaseImpl.java:41)
    at com.hp.cms.rtc.benchmarksuite.generators.load.UseCaseJob.execute(UseCaseJob.java:29)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

UPDATE:

Here is a source code excerpt from our connector that creates the connections to Hazelcast.

```
private HazelcastInstance hazelcastClient;
private IMap<Integer, Contact> contacts;
private IMap<Integer, Subscriber> subscribers;
private IMap<Integer, Account> accounts;
private IMap<Integer, Device> devices;
...

@Override
public void connect() {
    System.setProperty("hazelcast.logging.type", "none");
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    ClientNetworkConfig networkConf = new ClientNetworkConfig();
    networkConf.addAddress(url); // default: 127.0.0.1:5701
    clientConfig.setNetworkConfig(networkConf);
    hazelcastClient = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
    contacts = hazelcastClient.getMap("contacts");
    subscribers = hazelcastClient.getMap("subscribers");
    accounts = hazelcastClient.getMap("accounts");
    devices = hazelcastClient.getMap("devices");
    ...

    idGenContacts = hazelcastClient.getIdGenerator("idGenContacts");
    idGenContacts.init(0);
    idGenSubscribers = hazelcastClient.getIdGenerator("idGenSubscribers");
    idGenSubscribers.init(0);
    idGenAccounts = hazelcastClient.getIdGenerator("idGenAccounts");
    idGenAccounts.init(0);
    idGenDevices = hazelcastClient.getIdGenerator("idGenDevices");
    idGenDevices.init(0);
    ...
}
```

UPDATE 2:
I have increased the number of nodes to 3 and disabled the connection to the management center. This made it possible to reach something like 560 parallel connections before the exceptions occurred again. This time a different one was also displayed in addition to the one above:

```
com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetDisconnectedException: Target[Address[xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:5701] disconnected.
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection$CleanResourcesTask$1.createNew(ClientConnection.java:319)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection$CleanResourcesTask$1.createNew(ClientConnection.java:316)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection.cleanResources(ClientConnection.java:349)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection.access$200(ClientConnection.java:60)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection$CleanResourcesTask.run(ClientConnection.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
    at ------ End remote and begin local stack-trace ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientCallFuture.resolveResponse(ClientCallFuture.java:201)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientCallFuture.get(ClientCallFuture.java:142)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientCallFuture.get(ClientCallFuture.java:118)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:127)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientAtomicLongProxy.invoke(ClientAtomicLongProxy.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientAtomicLongProxy.getAndAdd(ClientAtomicLongProxy.java:98)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientAtomicLongProxy.getAndIncrement(ClientAtomicLongProxy.java:116)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientIdGeneratorProxy.newId(ClientIdGeneratorProxy.java:70)
    at com.hp.cms.rtc.benchmarksuite.dbconnectors.HazelcastConnectorImpl.insertNewCustomer(HazelcastConnectorImpl.java:325)
    at com.hp.cms.rtc.benchmarksuite.usecases.InsertNewCustomerUseCaseImpl.execute(InsertNewCustomerUseCaseImpl.java:41)
    at com.hp.cms.rtc.benchmarksuite.generators.load.UseCaseJob.execute(UseCaseJob.java:29)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing to create those connections? We have been running tests with a few thousand clients connecting to the cluster and we didn't see problems.

Comment: I have updated the question with additional source code from our connector. I also upgraded to Hazelcast 3.4, which delayed the occurrence of the exceptions a few dozens of parallel connections later (around 530). Tell me, if I can provide any additional details like the hazelcast.xml file or something.